# scrapy script - Load youtube csv or xml file into wordpress player or custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, youtube-api, scrapy, centos6.5

I have scrapy spider code which will scrap a webpage and pull the youtube video link into a file. I am trying to get that scrapy to run the url's as strings rather than a array.

This way my output is one URL without quotes, and then I wish to add text after the output of the URL. ",&source=Open YouTube Playlist"

*This way I can load the FULL url into a wordpress webplayer via native or a plugin, and it will auto-create a youtube list out of my output.*

**Maybe I am not thinking clearly? Is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?**

```
import scrapy

class PdgaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "pdgavideos"
start_urls = ["http://www.pdga.com/videos/"]

def parse(self, response):
    for link in response.xpath('//td[2]/a/@href').extract():
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), 
callback=self.parse_page)

    # If page contains link to next page extract link and parse
    next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., 
"Go\s+to\s+page\s+2")]/@href').extract_first()

    if next_page:
        yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), 
callback=self.parse)

# Youtube link 1st pass

def parse_page(self, response):

    link = response.xpath('//iframe/@src').extract_first()
    linkprune = link.split('/embed/')[+1]
    output = linkprune.split('?')[0]

    yield{
         'https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=': output + ','
    }
```

**Current Output**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=
"mueStjvHneI,"
"X7HfQL4fYgQ,"
"UtnR4gPMs_Q,"
"Kd9pbiKQqr4,"
"AokjaT-CnBk,"
"VdvhAsX6buo,"
"pF-XykcAqz8,"
"Fl0DDmx-jZw,"
"dpzLDiuQq9o,"
"J2_bl0zI504,"
```

...

**Aiming to achieve**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=mueStjvHneI,X7HfQL4fYgQ,UtnR4gPMs_Q,Kd9pbiKQqr4,VdvhAsX6buo,pF-XykcAqz8,dpzLDiuQq9o,&source=Open YouTube Playlist
```

If you load this URL, it will create a beautiful Youtube list.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: My apologies. I was trying not to ask too much, and instead I was too hypothetical. I have updated my question.